# Linking a Header to Another File

Tags: html, css, html-heading

I'm new to HTML and having some trouble linking a header to another file on my laptop. Most sites I searched said to follow this order: 
`<h4><a href="">Some Title</a></h4>`

I followed the order yet it is not linking properly:

```
<h4 id="aboutme"><a href="file:///Users/Name/Desktop/side%20project/my%20site/aboutme.html">About Me</a></h4>
```

Is there a technical reason why it isn't working? And if so how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a relative path instead. (This would be if the files are in the same folder for example)

```
<h4 id="aboutme"><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></h4>
```